# Remove minimize/maximize buttons from window, OpenTK

Tags: forms, minimize, maximize, opentk

I need to disable/remove the minimize and maximize buttons in window form.
I don't know how to access the form from my OpenTK.GameWindow, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is deceptively easy:

```
WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Hidden;
```

GameWindow does not use WinForms, it p/invokes the underlying platform directly (performance!)

Edit: or do you mean keep the close button but remove minimize/maximize? The closest to this is:

```
WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Fixed;
```

Comment: WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Fixed; Disabled the maximize button, but not the minimize button. Still, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's by design - I dislike applications that disable those buttons unnecessarily. If you do need that kind of flexiblity, you might be better off with a UI-centric tool, like WinForms+GLControl or GTK#+GLWidget, rather than GameWindow. (GameWindow is closer to SDL or GLUT in the grand scheme of things).